# Pytorch LSTM is much slower for a specific range of hidden sizes

Tags: python, pytorch

I'm looking into searching a broader range of hidden sizes for my model and encountered a major slowdown in a specific range.

I'm assuming that CUDA may be using different optimisations for different tensor sizes and the one used in this range are just not well supported by my hardware.

Any ideas on how I can get more performance in this range would be greatly appreciate.

This is the code to produce the plot below:

```
import torch
from torch import nn
import time
from plotly import graph_objs as go
from tqdm import tqdm


def test_speed(hidden_size, n=5, gpu=0):

    torch.random.manual_seed(42)

    model = torch.nn.LSTM(
            2,
            hidden_size,
            num_layers=3,
            batch_first=True,
            dropout=0.5,
    ).cuda(gpu)

    x = torch.randn(256, 180, 2).cuda(gpu)

    # Warmup
    model.forward(x)

    output = []
    t = time.time()

    for i in range(n):
        with torch.no_grad():
            y = model.forward(x)[0]
            
        output.append(y.mean().item())  # to force syncronization
        
    return (time.time() - t) / n, output


test_range = range(64, 256)

go.Figure(
    [
        go.Scatter(
            x=list(test_range),
            y=[test_speed(hidden_size, n=20, gpu=0)[0] for hidden_size in tqdm(test_range)],
            name="GPU 0",
        ),
    ],
    go.Layout(
        title="Mean forward pass time vs hidden size",
        xaxis_title="Hidden Size",
        yaxis_title="Time (s)"
    )
)
```

[image]

System:

i9 12th gen
RTX 3080 ti
cuda: 11.8
pytorch: 1.12.1

I've tried reinstalling / updating cuda and torch.
I was expecting a constant relationship between hidden size and forward pass time.

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you do any timing on GPU, always use `torch.cuda.synchronize()` ([see_here](https://auro-227.medium.com/timing-your-pytorch-code-fragments-e1a556e81f2)). If you alter your code to include it you'll see a more consistent prediction speed increase.

```
 def test_speed(hidden_size, n=5, gpu=0):

    torch.random.manual_seed(42)
    start = torch.cuda.Event(enable_timing=True)
    end = torch.cuda.Event(enable_timing=True)

    #start.record()
    model = torch.nn.LSTM(
            2,
            hidden_size,
            num_layers=3,
            batch_first=True,
            dropout=0.5,
    ).cuda(gpu)

    x = torch.randn(256, 180, 2).cuda(gpu)

    # Warmup
    model.forward(x)

    output = []
    t = time.time()
    start.record()
    for i in range(n):
        with torch.no_grad():
            y = model.forward(x)[0]

        output.append(y.mean().item())  # to force syncronization
    end.record()
    torch.cuda.synchronize()
    return start.elapsed_time(end),output
```

[image]

Comment: As an addendum, newer generations of GPUs have large performance gains for specific tensor sizes due to their use of tensor cores, so you will occasionally see unusual bumps for specific tensor shapes. See [this post](https://developer.nvidia.com/blog/optimizing-gpu-performance-tensor-cores/) for more information.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I did use synchronise originally but one of my GPU's was ignoring it for some reason so I opted to use .item to force python to wait for the computation to complete. I did run your code and got the same result. I'm curious what hardware you ran the test on?

Comment: Thanks @jhso, I think you're right about the tensor cores. Any idea on how I could get around that? It just seams wrong to me that a hidden size of 192 takes 17x the time to compute compared to a hidden size of 193. Do you think it's possible that there's a bug in the firmware causing it to dispatch operations to hardware that is impractical, something that a firmware update could fix? Or is this pretty normal behavior?

Comment: I did my computations on an RTX 2070. I believe it is just the way that tensor cores operate, in that this is actual good design practice in ML code to make batch sizes divisible by 8 and so on, as outlined in the post I linked above.

Comment: Note that the graph above isn’t based on tensor cores because it uses a FP32 graph. It would be interesting to do it again with AMP enabled.

Answer (score 0):

I found something of a workaround. Performance is much better in this range when using float16 (or automatic mixed precision when training) and hidden size on an interval of 8.

```
def test_speed(hidden_size, n=5, gpu=0, f16=False):

    torch.random.manual_seed(42)

    model = torch.nn.LSTM(
            2,
            hidden_size,
            num_layers=3,
            batch_first=True,
            dropout=0.5,
    ).cuda(gpu)

    x = torch.randn(256, 180, 2).cuda(gpu)

    if f16:
        x = x.half()
        model = model.half()

    # Warmup
    model.forward(x)

    output = []
    t = time.time()

    for i in range(n):
        with torch.no_grad():
            y = model.forward(x)[0]
        
        output.append(y.mean().item())  # to force syncronization
        
    return (time.time() - t) / n, output


test_range = range(64, 256)

go.Figure(
    [
        go.Scatter(
            x=list(test_range),
            y=[test_speed(hidden_size, n=20, gpu=1)[0] for hidden_size in tqdm(test_range)],
            name="float32",
        ),
        go.Scatter(
            x=list(test_range),
            y=[test_speed(hidden_size, n=20, gpu=1, f16=True)[0] for hidden_size in tqdm(test_range)],
            name="float16",
        ),
    ],
    go.Layout(
        title="Mean forward pass time vs hidden size",
        xaxis_title="Hidden Size",
        yaxis_title="Time (s)"
    )
)
```

[image]